# Compare this planet to Earth and determined its habitability (can humans live in this environment?)

Tags: exoplanet, spectral-type

I'm given this set of data and I need to describe the habitability. Would this not be habitable since the temperature of the albedo and the equilibrium is similar to Earth's or does the Spectral Type M affect the planet that much?

- Spectral Type: M
- Age of the Star (Gyr): 0.664
- Binary System: Single Star
- Planet Orbital Period (Years): 0.0387
- Planet Semi-Major Axis (AU): 0.0613
- Planet Mass (Earth Masses): 1.87
- Planet Radius (Earth Radii): 1.24
- Method of First Detection: Transit
- Eccentricity: 0.11
- Atmospheric Composition (Percent by Volume):

  N2  77.8
  CO2 0.00368
  H2O 2.37
  O2  19.8
- Number of other (known) Planets in the System: 1
- Location in the Galaxy: Open Cluster
- Distance from Earth (lightyears): 960
- Atmospheric Pressure (atm): 1
- Stellar Mass (Solar Masses): 0.154
- Planetary Albedo: 0.271
- Planet Equilibrium Temperature (K): 243
- Stellar Radius (Solar Radii): 0.171
- Orbital Inclination (degrees): 5.7
- Planet Axial Tilt (degrees): 18.4
- Magnetic Field Strength (Units of Earth Magnetic Field): 0.109

Comment: This doesn't seem to be real data. It is a made up world.

Comment: Your question looks unclear. Please fix it ASAP - a closure vote is going on.

Comment: Fried by UV and X-ray flares.

Comment: That high percentage of atmospheric oxygen is a bit suspicious, although I guess it could have been produced by UV photolysis of atmospheric water.

Comment: You should check out [this preprint by Schweiterman et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.04720) - even if they are habitable in the "supports liquid water" sense, planets around cooler red dwarfs are likely to build up lethal (to humans) levels of carbon monoxide.

Answer (score 2):

A very low mass M-dwarf (what you have there is something like an M5-M6 dwarf) will remain a highly magnetically active star for several billion years.

As such, the spectrum of light from such an object has a much higher proportion, by several orders of magnitude, of UV and X-ray emission than the Sun.

Therefore, if your planet is close enough to its star to receive a similar bolometric flux as the Earth does from the Sun, then it will get a very hefty dose of UV and X-rays. In addition to this, there will be flaring activity that raises these levels by more orders of magnitude for minutes or hours at a time.

There is not enough detail to know how well the planet is shielded from this, but it is unlikely to be habitable (by us).